# Implement custom logic when traversing path using Stream<Path>

Tags: java, stream, nio

I need to write a cronJob that needs to traverse a path and do some logic. This code is my start point:

```
try(Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(rootPath, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS)){
        walk.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).map(Path::toFile).peek(System.out::println).forEach(System.out::println);
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I need to do is:
I take the file, verify his name, if his name has some specific pattern, I need to delete him. I want to do this without creating a List because my folder can be 200-300 GB large. My question is: Can I implement some custom logic for each file, for example, a method that will take the file or his full name to do some logic and continue with the next file? **ex: .forEach(customMethod(fileName))**

Comment: A `FileVisitor` and `Files#walkFileTree` would probably work better for you.

Comment: "I want to do this without creating a List because my folder can be 200-300 GB large. " - note that the number of files does not necessarily correspond to their size and `File` does not contain the file contents but is just a reference to a file (which might not even exist yet). So I assume your 300GB directory won't have that many files unless it's all small files with just a couple of kilobytes.

Comment: @Thomas it's all small files, there can be hundreds of thousands of files.

Comment: Is it just the one directory, or are there sub-directories? And is it absolutely necessary to sort the files? Note I believe that your use of `sorted` causes all files (the paths, not the contents) to be buffered into memory.

Comment: @Slaw that folder contains files and subdirectories with files

Comment: And is the `sorted` necessary.?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this like this:

```
private static void deleteOrphanedMediaFilesUsingStreamEXAMPLE(final String path) throws IOException{
    Path dir = Paths.get(path);
    Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(dir, FileVisitOption.FOLLOW_LINKS);

    walk.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(path1 -> {
        String name = path1.getFileName().toString();
        //logic
    });
}
```